# Show image title in a javascript pop up?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I'm having trouble with a javascript pop up. I want the pop up to show the image reason/Title.

Anyone know what to do?

The code:

```
<?
    $badgesql = mysql_query("select * from usr_badge where user = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
    $user = mysql_query("select * from usr_users where username = '$_SESSION[usr_name]'");
    $usr = mysql_fetch_array($user);
    $vipsql = mysql_query("select * from usr_vip where userid = '$usr[id]'");
    $vipcheck = mysql_num_rows($vipsql);
    $badgecheck = mysql_num_rows($badgesql);
    $checkit = $badgecheck + $vipcheck;
    if($checkit==0)
    echo("You have 0 Badges");
    if($badgecheck!=0)
    {
    while($badge = mysql_fetch_array($badgesql))
    {
    echo('<img src="/css/badges/'.$badge[badge].'" onclick="alert('.$badge[reason].');" />');   }
    }
    //Display VIP Badges
    if($vipcheck!=0)
    {
    $vipbadge = mysql_fetch_array($vipsql);
    $vip1 = mysql_query("select * from usr_vipdb where id = '$vipbadge[vipid]'");
    $vip2 = mysql_fetch_array($vip1);
    echo('<img src="'.$vip2[url].'" alt="This user is a VIP!" />');
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Juhana. Well the code above works but it won't show the title of the image in a javascript pop up. I want to be able to click an image and the popup will appear with the title/reason.

Comment: Are you using any plugin to display the popup

Comment: No plugins. That's the whole code above..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you need some quotes within your `alert()`.

```
echo('<img src="/css/badges/'.$badge['badge'].'" onclick=\'alert("'.htmlentities($badge['reason']).'");\' />');
```

Also, `$badge[reason]` is bad practice (unless reason is a constant which I don't think is). Use single quotes like in the example above.

Finally, use `htmlentities()` when you're printing content to HTML.

Comment: No errors with this one but when you click the image it does not even pop up. Nothing is happening!

Comment: @NicholasPandie my mistake, I've edited the answer with the correction.

Answer (score 0):

The inline JavaScript isn't exactly a proper one. When you `echo` the string the `onclick` attribute will contain the value that looks something like:

```
alert(image reason);
```

You need to enclose the reason of the image with quotes for it to work properly. Thus, your code should look like this instead:

```
echo '<img src="/css/badges/'.$badge[badge].'" onclick="alert(\''.$badge[reason].'\');" />'
```